# Jquery CheckBox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

```
var $field = $(this);
            if ($field.is('input')) {
                alert(1);
                if ($field.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
                    alert(2);
                    if ($field.attr('value') == "true")
                        return $field.attr('checked');
                }

                return $field.val();
            }
```

I want to check if value of checkbox is true i add attribute checked = checked for checkbox. but my code is wrong. please help me.thanks

Comment: Can you give more context? It is not clear where "this" is.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `:checked` selector to greatly help with this.

```
var $field = $(this);
return $field.is(':checked');
```

This will return a proper bool. If you return the `attr('checked')` or the `val()`, you'll end up with a string, which is probably not what you want.

See http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/checked

Answer (score 6):

Change the condition to

```
$("input:checkbox").val() == "true"
```

and for checking the checkbox you can use

```
$("input:checkbox").attr ( "checked" , true );
```

You can select a checkbox using

```
$("input:checkbox")
```

and value using

```
$("input:checkbox").val()
```

If you want to check all the checkboxes with attribute value true then you can use

```
$(document).ready ( function ()
        {
            var checkBoxes = $("input:checkbox");           
            checkBoxes.each ( function () {
                if ( $(this).val() == "true" )
                {
                    $(this).attr ( "checked" , true );
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.attr('checked')
```

will return `true` for checked and `undefined` for unchecked

Answer (score 1):

CORRECTION:

```
.attr("checked")
```

will return "checked" if checked (not true), "undefined" if not checked.

If you want a true/false then you have to do something like this:

```
$("#checker").attr("checked")=="checked"
```